# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::filter()

Tags: php, laravel

Не получается настроить фильтрацию.

```
    public function index(OrderFilter $filter): View
    {
        $items = Order::withTrashed()->filter($filter)->paginate(10);

        return view($this->viewsPath . self::INDEX_ACTION, [
            'items' => $items,
            'perPage' => 10,
        ]);
    }
```

Получаю ошибку `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder::filter()`

Когда убираю `filter($filter)`, ошибка пропадает, фильтрация не работает.
Как правильно настроить фильтрацию?

where:

```
        $first = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('id');

        $items = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('id')
            ->union($first)
            ->get();
```

Comment: Потому что filter - это метод у Collection, а не у Builder. Как вам правильно подсказали, используйте либо where, либо [scopes](https://habr.com/ru/post/485520/).

Comment: Попробовал изменить (добавил выше в вопрос). Но теперь получаю ошибку ```Method Illuminate\Support\Collection::links does not exist.```

Answer (score 0):

Он не может найти Builder::filter() 
А почему не использовать where? 
В документации очень простая и легкая фильтрация
https://laravel.su/docs/8.x/queries#where-clauses

Обновление: 
Напишите, что вы хотите сделать. А то пока что вы перебираете фильтрацией одно и тоже
Метод union позволяет проводить слияние, а вы просто пытаетесь сделать фильтрацию одного и того же (в таблице orders столбца id 2 раза)

Если так хотите провести фильтрацию:

```
public function index(): 
    {
        $orders = DB::table('orders')
        ->where('id', '<', 100)
        ->get();

        return view('index', compact(['orders']));
    }
```

Потом просто выводите как обычно

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).